# how to avoid the spaces b/w the nodes/elements in saxon parser/xalon parser

Tags: java, xslt, xpath, saxon, xalan

I have input like following snippet,

***Input Snippet :***

```
    <div class="a">
      <table>
        <col width="4" />
        <col width="8" />
        <col width="5" />
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>ABC</td>
            <td>DEF </td>
            <td>GHI</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="x">

    <table>
        <col width="5" />
        <col width="8" />
        <col width="8" />
    <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>ABC</td>
            <td>DEF </td>
            <td>GHI</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I am currently at **table** inside of the **div class="a"** tag, and I would like check either the immediately following sibling that is **div** and it's first child is **table** or nothing. I wrote the following XPath: `./../following-sibling::div[1]/node()[1] ) = 'table'`.

I am getting expected output  in **altova XMLSpy**, but in **saxon parser** not giving exact output becasue there is some space between the `<div>` and `<table>`, and that space is treated as a text node.

How can I avoid the space between the tags, or are there any other solutions?

snippet Code :

```
<xsl:choose>

<xsl:when local-name(./../following-sibling::div[1]/node()[1] ) = 'table' ">    
  loagic-1
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
logic-2 
  </xsl:otherwise>

</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Ian's answer is correct, a cleaner solution is...

```
<xsl:when test="../following-sibling::div[1]/*[1]/self::table">
```

Also, if you didn't care about any intervening elements between the div and its table child, you could simplify to ...

```
<xsl:when test="../following-sibling::div[1]/table">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

at the top level of your style sheet, to tell it to ignore whitespace-only text nodes when parsing.